# Linux: Remove start entries only with file access

Tags: linux

I need to disable a service (in this case **bind9**) from the default Linux startup because I keeps freezing the system at startup.

I can't access the server via SSH or otherwise, i only have access to the hard drives.

Can I remove boot entries by modifying certain files on the HDD with another computer?

Comment: Of course you can, if you have access to the drive you can mount the file systems there and modify the OS to your hearts content.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can remove all links in the /etc/rc* directories if the distribution you have uses init. 
You can use the following command to list them:

```
find /etc/rc* -name '*bind*' -type l
```

To remove them use:

```
 find /etc/rc* -name '*bind*' -type l -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: it depend on distribution, for example systemd based distro or upstart distro and sysv distro

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will edit my post.